# Dispatch Event with a target.value in Jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine

How do I dispatch a `change` `Event` in a Jasmine unit test that includes a `target.value`?

The component under test has a method like this:

```js
@HostListener('change', ['$event'])
onChange(event) {
  const value = event.target.value;
  this.value = value;
}
```

See the `TODO` in my current unit test draft. I need to include the `target.value` when dispatching the event, but the `Event` interface does not seem to contain a `target` property.

```js
scenarios.forEach((scenario) => {
  it(`changing control value should result in correct value ${scenario.condition}`, fakeAsync(() => {
    // arrange
    component.writeValue(scenario.writtenControlValue);

    // act
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      const input = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input')).nativeElement;
      input.value = scenario.newControlValue;
      input.dispatchEvent(new Event('change')); // TODO: pass scenario.newControlValue to Event's target.value

      // assert
      expect(component.value).toEqual(scenario.expectedResult);
    });
  }));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [link](https://netbasal.com/simulating-events-in-angular-unit-tests-5482618cd6c6), maybe you can use `triggerEventHandler`.

```
scenarios.forEach((scenario) => {
  it(`changing control value should result in correct value ${scenario.condition}`, fakeAsync(() => {
    // arrange
    component.writeValue(scenario.writtenControlValue);

    // act
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      const input = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input'));
      input.nativeElement.value = scenario.newControlValue;
      input.triggerEventHandler('change', { target: input.nativeElement });


      // assert
      expect(component.value).toEqual(scenario.expectedResult);
    });
  }));
});
```

I also use this [link](https://medium.com/@penghuili/angular-unit-test-trigger-events-in-tests-7e9fb74014a9)  as a guide

Comment: Thanks! This does seem like a good approach. For some reason, it's not working for me (event handler isn't fired), but it's probably user error. For now, I am calling the event handler manually from the test rather than dispatching an event or using `triggerEventHandler`, which works, but is a bit hacky.